# UTC to local time - wrong result swift

Tags: swift, datetime, timezone, nsdateformatter, utc

I know there are a lot of threads, but I can't find a solution for my problem. Maybe I can't see the solution...

I receive a UTC Time: for example 12:50 
I want convert this time to MEZ respectively to the time zone of the users device. For my example I expect 13:50, because atm is MEZ +1 to UTC.

This is my code

```
    //transform date to string
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let newDateAsString:String = dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    //is 12:50 UTC 

    //transform date to MEZ respectively to the local device timezone
    let dateFormatterToDate = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterToDate.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    let timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier as String
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
    //same result with: dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

    //result is 11:50 but i would expect 13:50
    if let result = dateFormatterToDate.date(from: newDateAsString) {
        return result
    }
```

The result 11:50 is the time now in my current timezone. But I don't understand this. I give explicitly the date, which should convert. Somebody know where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion that you are doing is the opposite of what you intend. The string `newDateAsString`, which gives the time as 12:50, does not specify a timezone, because your date format string does not include formatting for a timezone. When you set `dateFormatterToDate`'s timezone to MEZ, and pass `newDateAsString` to `dateFormatterToDate`, you are saying: give me a `Date` object for 12:50 in MEZ.

By default Dates are displayed as UTC, so `result` is displayed as 11:50, because 12:50 in MEZ is 11:50 in UTC.

To format a date as a string in the local timezone you would use code like this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
let localTimeZoneDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: self)
```